# Why after reading XML file I see the special symbol "Ø" like: "�"

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP .Net project where I'm trying to upload it using Dropzone.js. Here is example of XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <user id="bk101">
        <name>Lorem</name>
        <surname>Ipsum</surname>
        <age>15</age>
        <description>Test 1592 Ø</description>
    </user>
    <user id="bk102">
        <name>Integer</name>
        <surname>Risus</surname>
        <age>29</age>
        <description>Test 1592 Ø</description>
    </user>
</catalog>
```

The problem is that after reading the file I'm getting:

```xml
...
    <description> Test 1592 � </description>
...
```

Here is how I'm reading and deserializing the file:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadXml(IFormFile xmlFile)
{
    if (xmlFile == null || xmlFile.Length == 0)
        return await Task.FromResult((string)null);

    using var reader = new StreamReader(xmlFile.OpenReadStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true);

    var strFile = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); //here I see already the �

    var newXmlInvoice = Deserialize<UserType>(strFile);
}


public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(new StringReader(input));
    else
        throw new ArgumentNullException(input, "The input parameter was null.");
}
```

The UserType class:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName="user")]
public class User {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="catalog")]
public class Catalog {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="user")]
    public List<User> User { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works fine reading and deserializing file. The only problem is "�" and I don't know why doesn't convert it. How can I fix this?

I know there are many questions and answers about how to convert special symbol, but I still didn't find any solutions. Please help!

Comment: Maybe you should use an other encoding instead of UTF8 ?

Comment: The � means that you are not sending your XML to `UploadXml` in UTF-8 that it expects.

Comment: I may be the viewer you are using to read the data.  XML is UTF-8 and you need to use a viewer that matches the encoding of the characters.  The people who generated the XML may be in France and you are reading the file in Germany.  So the viewer is set to German character and the character are French.

Comment: I'd suggest it was already invalid before you got to this function. As you can see from [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vbx1bY) if you read in UTF8 it should be OK

Comment: @jdweng XML itself is not in UTF-8, first and foremost because XML is a way of structuring data as opposed to a way of saving that structure to disk, a difference nicely explained [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). If a *particular* XML *file* happens to be in UTF-8 like you speculated, then it would not matter whether it was created in Germany or France, it would look identical and represent the same characters.

Comment: @GSerg : XML-8 is UTF-8 meaning that data is transferred without any data changing.  Encoding methods filter data so not all characters can be sent.  The issue is the way characters are displayed.  For example Notepad has different a different character set depending on the culture settings.  If the culture is not the same where the xml is generated and where it is being used you will get the � character.

Comment: @jdweng No, it does not happen that way. Unicode encodes characters regardless locales, that was the point of inventing it. The � character is the [Unicode replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) which has nothing to do with Notepad or fonts.

Comment: @GSerg  PIt definitely does work this way and solved lots of OIPs issues by simply changing setting on viewer.  Often just required changing Notepad default settings.

Comment: Your sample xml already specifies an encoding, and it's not utf-8

Comment: @GSerg : I've seen lots of cases where applications were developed in one country and people using the apps were seeing the � when notepad was set to an ASCII font.  Simply changing the font to use a FONT that was compatible to the developing country letters solved the issue.